# React : material-ui-pickers date-io Jalaali Utils returns error : TypeError: utils.getDayText is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

This is NOT a duplication of https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1440 because I don't have problems with the original usage.
According to this link here https://material-ui-pickers.dev/localization/calendar-systems I have used JalaliUtils from @date-io/jalaali. Here is my code and you can see that I have used two different utils which with JalaaliUtils I get two errors of:

> TypeError: utils.getDayText is not a function
>
> TypeError: utils.getYearText is not a function

Instead it works just fine if I use MomentUtils from @date-io/moment but this is not what I want.
is there any bugs with the package itself ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import jMoment from "moment-jalaali";
import JalaliUtils from "@date-io/jalaali";
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import {
  DatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

jMoment.loadPersian({ dialect: "persian-modern", usePersianDigits: true });

function PersianExample() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(moment());

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={JalaliUtils} locale="fa">
        <DatePicker
          clearable
          okLabel="ok"
          cancelLabel="cancel"
          clearLabel="clear"
          labelFunc={date => (date ? date.format("jYYYY/jMM/jDD") : "")}
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
        <DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default PersianExample;
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "search-documents",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "1.x",
    "@date-io/jalaali": "^2.3.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "1.x",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^8.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/moment-jalaali": "^0.7.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^12.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.20",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-advance-jalaali-datepicker": "^1.2.2",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-relay": "^8.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "yup": "^0.28.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your package.json? Which version of @date-io do you use?

Comment: Yes I added my package.json

Comment: Please check the comment for @date-io v2.0.0 https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io/releases :
Do not update if you are using @material-ui/pickers v3

Comment: yes I think I should downgrade @date-io/jalaali version too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use 1.x version `npm install @date-io/jalaali@1.x`

Comment: Had same problem, in my case worked when I downgraded to 1.2.0 of @date-io/luxon package